# Is there any way that I can only run a single condition will send mail?

Tags: php, laravel, email

This is my code:

```
if( 
        $form->user_mail_address && $form->model()->user_mail_address == $form->user_mail_address &&
        $form->user_nickname && $form->model()->user_nickname == $form->user_nickname &&
        $form->user_sex && $form->model()->user_sex == $form->user_sex &&
        $form->user_area && $form->model()->user_area == $form->user_area &&
        $form->user_generation && $form->model()->user_generation == $form->user_generation && 
        $form->status == Post::STATUS_APPROVED) {
            Mail::send(new DepositMail($form->model()->id, $form->model()->user_mail_address));
            Mail::send(new DepositMail($form->model()->id));}
```

As here I am trying when admin only change the status will send a mail to user email. But I think it's way too long. Will it have other method that will not need to use that long method to send the mail when only admin change the user status? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use userId as your identifier, also this makes your code clean and easy to understand.

```
if ($form->status == Post::STATUS_APPROVED && $form->userId == $selectedUserId){
 //send mail
}
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. I have try this method before, it will still end up when I change the gender or other will trigger to send mail to use. So, how can I make an exception that only send a mail when admin change user status?

Comment: @eduu1688 can you post your blade also?

Comment: @ Poldo my blade is a bit hard to show, cause it is in other language then English. What should I do with the blade file. Cause I think the mail sending issues is mail in the controller.

Comment: @eduu1688 I advice you to reset the form or atleast make some field to its initial value.

Comment: When user apply the form, I have set as 0, which mean is waiting to approve. When status approve, it will be 10, reject will be -10.

Comment: try to use dd() in your controller to check for form data. e.g. dd($request->all());